# Why does iosched use getFragmentManager and not getSupportFragmentManager?

Tags: iosched

Why does the iosched app use getFragmentManager instead of getSupportFragmentManager?  I was under the assumption that if you're using the support classes you should 'go all the way'.  Can someone explain the reasoning behind this?

I'm trying to move my app to Material Design and assumed that even though I support 4.0 and up I would have to use the support fragments.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption was wrong.  You don't need to use support fragments, native fragments work just fine.